# Can not boot! Failed to start AppArmor initialization... Computer hanging in booting.. can not start

Tags: boot, apparmor

My HP Elitebook 2570p cannot boot! Failed to start AppArmor initialization... Computer hanging in booting process starting gnome display manager, dispatcher service....system changes .. p link was shut down. I can not start my laptop anymore. I use the up-to-date Ubuntu. I restarted my laptop and since now it has been stuck in booting mode. 
What can I do now?

[image]

Comment: What did you do prior to this crash ?   

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006529/failed-to-start-apparmor-initialization

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/973765/apparmor-initialization-failed-in-ubuntu-17-10/976082

Comment: i deinstalled tor browser (only) and tried to watch a movie..

Answer (score 2):

When you see that crash screen try to get into the console by issuing

```
ctrl + alt + F3
```

if this gives you a text terminal login prompt then login and issue

```
 sudo apt-get install apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu
```

Lets try a new strategy ... reboot box and then immediately start to tap shift key repeatedly until you see the following :

[image: purple grub screen]

use your arrow keys to scroll down to grub menu option :

***Advanced options for Ubuntu***

and hit enter ... now you will see this screen

[image: Advanced options]

again arrow key yourself down and hit enter on menu option `root`

now you should see a terminal prompt logged on as root ... if yes then issue

```
 sudo apt-get install apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu
```

Please tell how you get on

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76895/discussion-on-answer-by-scott-stensland-can-not-boot-failed-to-start-apparmor-i).

Answer (score 1):

if the recovery mode doesn't make it to the options screen as I saw with an 18.04 bionic - append `init=/bin/sh` to the line beginning with "linux" in the edit-mode for grubs menu item of "recovery" (key for edit: ctrl+e, boot with changed options: ctrl+x).

When you're dropped to a shell, remount the rootfs (`mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdaX /`) and delete the symlink of the apparmor.service to the sysinit.target (`find /etc/systemd/ -name '*apparmor*'`) and restart.

After the now successful boot I suggest to create an override for the apparmor.service unit-file and set a TimeoutSec=20 to it.

Either `systemctl edit apparmor.service` or create the path leading up to and into the conf file `/etc/systemd/system/apparmor.service.d/override.conf`:

```
[Service]
TimeoutSec=
TimeoutSec=20s
```

Then you can install missing packages via apt or debug apparmor, in any way a boot can be more forgiving if apparmor is failing.

Comment: Probably you meant `sysinit.target` (without 'v'), didn't you?
Apart from that your answer is a real life-saver.
About the hint to override the apparmor.service unit-file, I'd still like to get a hint how, if possible.

Comment: On it again for another update I realized that the overrride is described and I added it now to my system. To clarify things, the timeout is just stopping apparmor from waiting long time and rendering the system unusable. following the advice here I was able to finish the upgrade as apparmor blocked many update-steps. That doesn't  solve my basic problems with apparmor, but I could move on,