# Laptop loses power while updating then Failed to start AppArmor initialization?

Tags: dpkg

I was updating my Ubuntu to  the latest updates but I forgot to plug my laptop and it loses its power. Now after I enter my password, it goes black like in this link [Can not boot! Failed to start AppArmor initialization... Computer hanging in booting.. can not start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030586/can-not-boot-failed-to-start-apparmor-initialization-computer-hanging-in-boo) and had tried doing the solution for it. But it does not work and it says

W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: dpkg was intrrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure - a' to correct the prblem.
But when I tried dpkg --configure -a it says
dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: Read-only file system

any help??

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your root partition contains no errors, try to remount it:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

and run dpkg again:

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

If you aren't sure your root partition has some errors caused by power interruption, force a check of all filesystems:

```
fsck -Af -M
```

The last `fsck` command will check all of the filesystems except mounted. To force check of root filesystem look at list of partitions first:

```
fdisk -l
```

find your root `/` partition, for example, /dev/sda1 or something like this and run `fsck` for the root filesystem:

```
fsck -f -y /dev/sda1
```

Finally reboot computer

```
reboot
```

and try to fix error again using `dpkg` and `mount` as stated above.